by using :nth-of-type I'm trying to select the fist div inside the div #benefits-section, but for some reason it selects all div tags
Following are the HTML and CSS that I'm working on.
    https://jsfiddle.net/mpgsrwt0/

 #benefits-section h2{
display: block;
font-size: 2rem;
font-family: Outfit;
font-weight: 500;
margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#benefits-section div:nth-of-type(1){
background-color: yellow;
}

When I try using the nth of type on the second and third div, it works.
OR when I try using the selector for the first div, it stops working. it selects all the div tags and applies background on it. I'm not sure what is causing this error.

A proper [mre] of your issue should be contained directly inside your question, please do not just put it up on external platforms.

I tried, but it just wouldn't let me. That's why I had to post on jsfiddle. It was triggering the message "Your question is mostly code" even after I put the bare minimum CSS and HTML code and provided proper justification.

All the inner divs you have are the first children of that type so they are correctly all colored yellow.
You want to target only the div that is the direct child (not a grandchild), so change this:

     #benefits-section div:nth-of-type(1) {
       background-color: yellow;
     }

to this:
     #benefits-section > div:nth-of-type(1) {
       background-color: yellow;
     }


Thank you so much! It was so simple; how could I forget!! I'll have to take a refresher course in CSS selectors, I've recently started developing again after years. I need to brush up a lot.
